# Analytical solution for a Non-linear differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = A\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)+B \sin(2Cy)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, nonlinear-system

Analytical solution for a non-linear differential equation:

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = A \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)+ B \sin(2Cy)$

A,B are non-zero constants and y (position) is a scalar-value parameter which is a function of t (time).

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Why do you think an analytical solution exists? 3. Why do you have the tags 'PDE', 'partial derivative' and 'nonlinear-system'  when none of those things are relevant to your problem?

Comment: On the contrary, it'll be solvable for $y''=ay'+b\sin ct$ instead.

Comment: $y=n\pi/(2C)$ is a solution for any integer $n$.